# populating a list given certain conditions in swift ui xcode 11.5

Tags: ios, xcode, list, navigation, swiftui

I am a very entry-level in programming and swift.

I am trying to make an app that shows cities and their own landmarks, restaurants, etc. 
The flow of the app is expected to follow this order: 
View with list of the cities /
View with categories (landmarks, restaurants , etc) for each city /
View of list of landmarks, restaurants, etc. /
Detail view of that object

I managed to populate each category list with their relative objects, but they are shown in every single city, rather than the one they relates to.

Example: "Milan / Landmarks / Coliseum" and "Rome / Landmarks / Coliseum";
as you know, Coliseum is only in Rome, lol.

How can i fix this?

Is there anything to do with the initialisation of the objects or with the navigation?

Thanks in advance

```
import SwiftUI

struct CategoryView: View {

var category: Category



var body: some View {

    VStack{
        //circle image
        Image(uiImage: category.categoryLogo)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 12)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)

        Text(category.categoryName)
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)


        List(elements) { element in
            NavigationLink(destination:
                ElementView(element: element)) {
                    if self.category.categoryName == element.elementCategory.rawValue  {
                        ElementRow(element: element)
                    }

            }

        }


        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.top, 25)

}
}
```

This is the Model:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Province: Identifiable {
var id: Int

var provinceName: String
var provinceBannerImage: UIImage
var provinceLogoImage: UIImage
var provinceDescription: String

}


struct Element: Identifiable {

var id: Int

var elementName: String
var elementTown: String
var elementProvince: String

var elementDescription: String
var elementLogo: UIImage
var elementImageBanner: UIImage

var elementCategory: String

}

struct Category: Identifiable {

var id: Int

var categoryName: String
var categoryLogo: UIImage

}
```

Comment: Welcome @DarioGIn on StackOverflow, I would request you to attach your code snippet. It will help community members to answer your question easily. for more help please visit  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not an issue with your UI Code, it's a bug in your model and data.
Post the model code for more help.

Comment: Thanks Uday, just uploaded the model

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the structure of data. Can you print your underlying raw data, such as JSON format?